# RHEL KVM stuck when trying to create VM under VMware Fusion

Tags: rhel, virtual-machine, kvm, vmware-fusion

I am trying to use KVM on RHEL 7 VM but after I try to create a new VM it goes well until I click Finish button, at that moment the window stuck and does not respond anymore, so I can't create a VM!

That's what I used: - VMware Fusion Professional Version 11.0.0 (10120384) - RHEL 7 + KVM - Mac book pro with Mojave - I enabled the VTx feature on VMware Fusion.

Here you can see a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated the RedHat and everything is ok now but unfortunately, the new kernel caused the GUI to stop working but with the update and the old kernel I could use the system as required.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a VMware Fusion Pro version with almost a year.

I would use 11.1.0 for Mojave instead, that was out last week, and brings at least, besides bug fixes:

- compatibility for RHEL 8.0;
- fix for virtual disk image conversion bugs;
- new versions of vmware tools.

I would consider using RHEL 8.0 instead, if in an home/lab setting.

Comment: Are there anything else I have to do in terms of configurations?

Comment: I updated fusion to ver 11.1 but with no luck, and I need to use RHEL 7. Any other suggestions?